# Logarithmic UISlider

Tags: cocoa-touch, uislider

Are there any preferred methods for having a UISliders values change logarithmically, rather than linearly? So that, for example, the value changes from 0 to 25 over the first half of the slider, and 25 to 100 over the second half.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.  But you can convert the `float` value that the slider gives into the numbers you need.  Here's an example.

```
float interpretedValue;
if (sliderValue < 0.5) {
    interpretedValue = sliderValue * 25 / 0.5;
} else {
    interpretedValue = (sliderValue - 0.5)*(100 - 25)/0.5 + 25;
}
```

I've left some of the constants in the equations so you can tweak more easily.  But for maximum performance I'd simplify them.

**Edit, Jan 17, 2013:**

I've been asked to provide a set of equations that can find the slider value given the interpreted value.  Here they are:

```
float sliderValue;
if (interpretedValue < 25) {
    sliderValue = interpretedValue * 0.5 / 25;
} else {
    sliderValue = (interpretedValue - 25) * 0.5 / (100 - 25) + 0.5;
}
```